# system file checker

Tags: c++

I am using an API SfcIsFileProtected() to verify whether a file is integrated or not,
It seems like this API always return true even though I am manually changing a dll which is under system file checker or just deleting it.

BTW - From command line I am getting an answer that this specific file is violated.

This is the code I am using:

```
    BOOL result = SfcIsFileProtected(NULL, fileName);
if (FALSE == result) {
    std::cout << fileName << " is not integrated" << std::endl;
}
else {
    std::cout << fileName << " TRUE TRUE TRUE it is integrated" << std::endl;
}
return result;
```

Any idea on how I can get back a reliable answer of using this API in windows 7 platform ?

Comment: `SfcIsFileProtected` doesn't tell you if a file is violated, it tells you if a file is under SFC protection.

Comment: Reading the documentation on [Windows resource protection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc185681%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of which the function is a part of, it seems to me that it doesn't have anything to do with file updates.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response - So the question is what API available to check if a specific file is violated or not in windows 7 platform? I understand from your answer that changing/replacing a file/dll which is under SFC protection by taking its ownership from the operating system  doesn't mean taking it off SFC protection => in this case the API SfcIsFileProtected() will return true ?